# Spring MVC + Hibernate

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

i've a problem with hibernate configuration in Spring.
My project is a repository project. This is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Framework-core-data-oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>Framework-core-data-oracle</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This are my beans definition:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This is my hibernate config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.4:1521:BAGSTORAGE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">bagstorage!</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">BAGSTORAGE</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When i try to autowire SessionFactory i've got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource -> nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

I have spring orm added in pom, spring mvc version is > 3, so there is no problem with hibernate 4. Any ideas?

I've this situation:
Project A: core project, with spring dependency in maven
Project B: Repository project, where there are core project (project A), hibernate-core, oracle and spring-orm dependencies
Project C: Work project, with beans configurations and project A and project B in dependencies

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks correct, but I see you depend on `spring-core` 3.1.1 and `spring-orm` 4.0.0. 
You really should align the versions of all your Spring modules. Please try to upgrade `spring-core` to version 4.0.0 and see if the error goes away ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but same error with configuration aligned :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a class is not loaded/found, there are 2 reasons:

```
1. There are multiple versions of it in the classpath(2+ artifacts containing it)
2. There is no class defined in the classpath
```

You have different versions for Spring modules, it is usually a best practice to keep them in sync, like this:

```
<properties>
  <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've tried with same version of spring and spring-orm, and all reference are specified only one time. I've always the same error.

I've this situation:
Project A: core project, with spring dependency in maven
Project B: Repository project, where there are core project (project A), hibernate-core, oracle and spring-orm dependencies
Project C: Work project, with beans configurations and project A and project B in dependencies

Comment: @user2992626 make sure that you don't have a transitive dependency that duplicates a dependency. I believe that you posted the B or C's POM, maybe you get something from project A. Try to comment out all the dependencies in these projects and rely on A's dependencies and and add them one by one until it's back compiling and running. You will be sure that's not a classpath problem at least.